# Can I use the Jenkins REST API with user input?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, api, slack

I want my Jenkins Pipeline to have a user input step where it posts to a slack channel and waits for user input then uses the input to user enters (button in the slack message).

So at the input step it posts to slack with a message that has buttons.

Then when a user clicks a button in slack a rest call or something hits Jenkins with the value of the button user pressed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi! Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606237/8442153  , or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49493403/8442153

Comment: @dalmo.santos could you post this as an answer?

Comment: This I think is just linking back to the jenkins job- user still needs to login to jenkins https://stackoverflow.com/a/49493403/8442153. This requires a POST https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606237/8442153 - how can you have slack send a POST request when a user clicks a button?

Comment: @red888 please clarify the flow. E.g. jenkins job runs and then it shows a button, the user clicks on the button, a message appears in Slack. Please verify whether this is correct. Please explain what you mean with `So at the input step it posts to slack with a message that has buttons`. Does this mean that a button should appear in Slack?

Comment: yes so they dont have to log into jenkins at all. jenkins sends them a slack message with a button. they press the button in slack it sends jenkins some value